# Unable to start Hbase master in Pseudo distributed mode on single node

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I have just started learning about Hadoop.

I run **Hadoop 2.0.0** on Cloudera CDH4 with **Hbase 0.94.12** on CentOS.

I run the command service hbase-master start which starts the server only for few seconds.

The `jps` shows this result :

```
29300 SecondaryNameNode
3354 NodeManager
3032 RunJar
2957 RunJar
2552 HRegionServer
4016 Jps
3432 ResourceManager
2312 HQuorumPeer
30345 QuorumPeerMain
29228 NameNode
2671 JobHistoryServer
29157 DataNode
```

**Also, this is the exact error log**

```
2013-10-15 08:30:35,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ActiveMasterManager: Deleting ZNode for /hbase/backup-masters/127.0.0.1,60000,1381818635067 from backup master directory
2013-10-15 08:30:35,643 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Node /hbase/backup-masters/127.0.0.1,60000,1381818635067 already deleted, and this is not a retry
2013-10-15 08:30:35,643 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ActiveMasterManager: Master=127.0.0.1,60000,1381818635067
2013-10-15 08:30:35,768 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTrimmed(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$Conf.<init>(DFSClient.java:306)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.getRootDir(FSUtils.java:667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:536)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:396)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2013-10-15 08:30:35,790 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Aborting
2013-10-15 08:30:35,790 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Stopping service threads
2013-10-15 08:30:35,791 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: Stopping server on 60000
2013-10-15 08:30:35,791 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer: IPC Server handler 0 on 60000: exiting
```

Also My hbase-site.xml configurations are as under :

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.master</name>
             <value>master_hostname:60000</value>
            <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.</description>
        </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2182</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
            <value>300</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
            <value>/var/lib/zookeeper</value>
        <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
                The directory where the snapshot is stored.
        </description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

This is my hbase-env.sh file :

```
# Set environment variables here.

# This script sets variables multiple times over the course of starting an hbase process,
# so try to keep things idempotent unless you want to take an even deeper look
# into the startup scripts (bin/hbase, etc.)

# The java implementation to use.  Java 1.6 required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40

# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Optional.
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/etc/hadoop/conf

# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
export HBASE_HEAPSIZE=4096

# Extra Java runtime options.
# Below are what we set by default.  May only work with SUN JVM.
# For more on why as well as other possible settings,
# see http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/PerformanceTuning
export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"

# Uncomment one of the below three options to enable java garbage collection logging for the server-side processes.

# This enables basic gc logging to the .out file.
# export SERVER_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"

# This enables basic gc logging to its own file.
# If FILE-PATH is not replaced, the log file(.gc) would still be generated in the HBASE_LOG_DIR .
# export SERVER_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:<FILE-PATH>"

# This enables basic GC logging to its own file with automatic log rolling. Only applies to jdk 1.6.0_34+ and 1.7.0_2+.
# If FILE-PATH is not replaced, the log file(.gc) would still be generated in the HBASE_LOG_DIR .
# export SERVER_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:<FILE-PATH> -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=1 -XX:GCLogFileSize=512M"

# Uncomment one of the below three options to enable java garbage collection logging for the client processes.

# This enables basic gc logging to the .out file.
# export CLIENT_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"

# This enables basic gc logging to its own file.
# If FILE-PATH is not replaced, the log file(.gc) would still be generated in the HBASE_LOG_DIR .
# export CLIENT_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:<FILE-PATH>"

# This enables basic GC logging to its own file with automatic log rolling. Only applies to jdk 1.6.0_34+ and 1.7.0_2+.
# If FILE-PATH is not replaced, the log file(.gc) would still be generated in the HBASE_LOG_DIR .
# export CLIENT_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:<FILE-PATH> -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=1 -XX:GCLogFileSize=512M"

# Uncomment below if you intend to use the EXPERIMENTAL off heap cache.
# export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize="
# Set hbase.offheapcache.percentage in hbase-site.xml to a nonzero value.


# Uncomment and adjust to enable JMX exporting
# See jmxremote.password and jmxremote.access in $JRE_HOME/lib/management to configure remote password access.
# More details at: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html
#
# export HBASE_JMX_BASE="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
# export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS="$HBASE_MASTER_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10101"
# export HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS="$HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10102"
# export HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS="$HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10103"
# export HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_OPTS="$HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10104"

# File naming hosts on which HRegionServers will run.  $HBASE_HOME/conf/regionservers by default.
# export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=${HBASE_HOME}/conf/regionservers

# File naming hosts on which backup HMaster will run.  $HBASE_HOME/conf/backup-masters by default.
# export HBASE_BACKUP_MASTERS=${HBASE_HOME}/conf/backup-masters

# Extra ssh options.  Empty by default.
# export HBASE_SSH_OPTS="-o ConnectTimeout=1 -o SendEnv=HBASE_CONF_DIR"

# Where log files are stored.  $HBASE_HOME/logs by default.
# export HBASE_LOG_DIR=${HBASE_HOME}/logs

# Enable remote JDWP debugging of major HBase processes. Meant for Core Developers 
# export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS="$HBASE_MASTER_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8070"
# export HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS="$HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8071"
# export HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS="$HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8072"
# export HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_OPTS="$HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8073"

# A string representing this instance of hbase. $USER by default.
# export HBASE_IDENT_STRING=$USER

# The scheduling priority for daemon processes.  See 'man nice'.
# export HBASE_NICENESS=10

# The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
# export HBASE_PID_DIR=/var/hadoop/pids

# Seconds to sleep between slave commands.  Unset by default.  This
# can be useful in large clusters, where, e.g., slave rsyncs can
# otherwise arrive faster than the master can service them.
# export HBASE_SLAVE_SLEEP=0.1

# Tell HBase whether it should manage it's own instance of Zookeeper or not.
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

Any help is welcome :)

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show me your complete HMaster log file?Pastebin or something...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7ePDzLiE : This is my recent Hmaster log file. I hope this helps.

Comment: Please make sure that there is no problem with the HDFS configuration and that HBase is properly picking the configuration and all the HDFS libraries. Looks like the FileSystem implementation for your default FS can't be found. Showing your configuration xmls would be helpful.

Comment: Although 0.94.x releases are compatible with Hadoop 2.x, have you considered upgrading to a newer release, say 0.94.7 which was released recently?

Comment: I have recently added hadoop jars to hbase lib folder..which makes hbase master run. But when I try to create a table in hbase shell, it gives org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException.

Comment: I have updated my post with the config files for your reference.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. I was in transit and outta coverage. What's the current status. Any luck???

Comment: Nope. Not yet. Still facing the same bug. Any ideas to resolve this issue?

Comment: Let me know whenever you are ol we'll continue this over the chat otherwise we'll end up with too many unnecessary comments.